# How to force not longer displayed or add ellipsis at the end when a vbox is exceeded

Tags: framed, box

Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frame{\vbox to .3\textheight{
    \lipsum[1]\lipsum[10]\
}}
\end{document}
```

i only need the text within the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an overkill. With Ti*k*Z you can use clip. (**Update**: Typo corrected, big thanks to frougon.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\myindent
\begin{document}
\myindent=\parindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,-0.3\textheight);
\node[anchor=north west,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
align=justify] at (0,0){\hspace{\myindent}\lipsum[1]\lipsum[10]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\frame{\vbox to .3\textheight{
    \lipsum[1]\lipsum[10]\
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, didn't you mean ``\clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,-0.3\textheight);`` (i.e., ``0.3\textheight`` instead of ``0.3\textwidth``)?